# How to contribute to a list property of a bean using Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 projects:

- framework
- product-a
- product-b

Each of the products depends on the framework, but they don't know each other.

I have 3 spring configuration files: one for each project. The configuration file of each product includes (with `<import resource="classpath:/...`) the configuration file of the framework.

In the framework there is a bean called "manager", which has a property `List<AnInterface> theList`. The "manager" has a addXxx(anImplementation), which adds elements to the list).

The framework, and each of the product provide implementations of `AnInterface`, which have to be added to `theList`.

So in the end, when product-a is running, the manager contains implementations from the framework, and from product-a, idem for product-b

**What is the best practice to perform this initialization with Spring ?**

The only solution I could think about is to create a dedicated class which contructor will take the manager and a list of contributions, and add them to the manager, but it's ugly because 1/ It manipulate external objects in the constructor, 2/ I have to create a dummy class just to initialize other classes... I don't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that code should not know about Spring if it is not really needed. Therefore I would do all initialization in Spring config.

We can use [bean definition inheritance](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions) and property overriding to do it.

Framework class

```
public class Manager {

    private List<AnInterface> theList;

    public void init() {
         // here we use list initialized by product
    }    

}
```

Framework context

```
<bean id="manager"
      init-method="init"
      abstract="true"
      class="Manager">
    <property name="theList">
        <list/> <!-- this will be overriden or extnded -->    
    </property>
</bean>
```

Product A context

```
<bean id="managerA"
      parent="manager"
      scope="singleton"
      lazy-init="false">
    <property name="theList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="impl1"/>
            <ref bean="impl2"/>
        </list>    
    </property>
</bean>
```

Watch out for parent and child properties in such configuration. Not all are inherited from parent. Spring documentation specifies:

> The remaining settings are always taken from the child definition: depends on, autowire mode, dependency check, singleton, scope, lazy init.

Moreover, there is also [collection merging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-merging) in Spring so by specifing in child bean

```
<list merge="true">
```

you can merge parent and child lists.

---

I have observed this pattern in a number of projects and some extendable Web frameworks based on Spring.

Comment: I have sucessfully implemented this pattern, and I don't want to abuse of your time, but for my own guidance, would you please provide links the the Web frameworks you mention, if that's doesn't take too much of your time ? tx

Comment: @SamuelRossille A big commercial one is hybris platform. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybris_%28company%29

Comment: @SamuelRossille And open source one is Liferay. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay Those two I worked with.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted the answer of Grzegorz because it's a clean solution to my initial problem, but here as an alternate answer, the a technical solution to contribute to a list property of an existing bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="manager"/>
<property name="targetMethod"><value>addXxx</value></property>
<property name="arguments"><list value-type="com.xxx.AnInterface">
    <value ref="impl1" />
    <value ref="impl2" />
    ...
    </list></property>
</bean>
```